# showing "branch main -> FETCH_HEAD Already up to date." while pulling. How to fix this?

Tags: github, request, pull

I'm a collaborator in a git repo, when I wanted to pull using the command "git pull origin main", it said:

From https://github.com/Joty46/KutiBari

* branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD

Already up to date.

But my local repo isn't updated, I can't pull and tried many solutions, nothing worked. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

https://saywebsolutions.com/blog/git-github-error-fatal-couldnt-find-remote-ref-master

I tried the solutions from the above link but I'm stuck at step 3. It says:

To https://github.com/Joty46/KutiBari.git

! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Joty46/KutiBari.git'

I've also tried step 4, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you face an issue like that, instead of pulling the branch from the origin, delete the branch in git, and then fetch the branch from the origin. it will work